# Xcode auto-quit in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, xcode

On Lion, Xcode quit on its own when it was downloading documentation with no windows open. Is it safe to have Xcode download documentation in Mountain Lion or will it still quit on its own if all windows are closed?

Comment: one thing to be clear about  is that its not Xcode that is quitting itself. Its OS X that is quitting Xcode.

Comment: Auto termination is dependent on how Xcode indicates its status to OS X, which is Xcode version depended if there were changes made, which version of Xcode is this about? An Xcode version that auto terminates on Lion should also auto terminate on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X 10.8.1 no longer automatically terminates Xcode 4.4.1 while Xcode is downloading documentation with no windows open. It looks like "they fixed the glitch" of Xcode not properly communicating its "working" status to OS X. Have not tried on Lion, but I would guess that Xcode 4.4.1 no longer is auto-terminated there too when  downloading documentation.

Answer (score 1):

According to [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/15/disable-automatic-termination-of-apps-in-mac-os-x/), you can disable auto-terminate in Lion and Mountain Lion with the following terminal command:

```
defaults write -g NSDisableAutomaticTermination -bool yes
```

This sets the NSDisableAutomaticTermination flag in the `defaults` database that OS X consults to get various settings.

Note that this will disable automatic termination for *all* applications, not just Xcode.

Comment: Accepting MrDaniel's answer (because it was the answer) and upvoting this one because it tells me how to disable that stupid functionality. Ta!